# How to limit lenght of a complicated line in Python?

Tags: python, pep8, continuation

I'm formatting my code according to [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), but I have a little issue; this is it:

```
print ("DB Updated: " + datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(stats_dict["db_update"])).strftime('%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y'))
```

How to break it into lines with 72-79 characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime

dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(stats_dict["db_update"]))
print("DB Updated: " + dt.strftime('%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y'))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
timestamp = int(stats_dict["db_update"])
d = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
msg = "DB Updated: {}".format(d.strftime('%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y'))
print(msg)
```

Comment: The second line is too long (80 chars). Consider possible identation.

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer:

```
print("DB Updated: " + 
    datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
        int(stats_dict["db_update"])
    ).strftime('%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')
)
```

Note that you don't need line continuation symbols as long as the whole expression is in braces.

Temporary variables <s>suck</s> decrease readability, in my opinion.

OP's update: I modified your answer as follows:

```
 print("DB Updated: " +
      datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
        int(stats_dict["db_update"])).
        strftime('%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y'))
```

Comment: it is a mess. To understand it you need to jump to 3rd line, then 2nd, then 4th, then 1st. Compare it with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13155636/4279)

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime

dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(stats_dict["db_update"]))
print("DB Updated: {:%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y}".format(dt))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print ("DB Updated: " + datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(\
     int(stats_dict["db_update"]))\
     .strftime('%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y'))
```